# Android Gradle: How to change property file value based on buildType value?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

During the build process, I'd like to change the value of a property in an existing property file depending on whether it's a release or debug build.

File: res/raw/app.property

> key=value-prod

During the debug build, I want to set `key=value-debug` and for release set `key=value-prod`

Can this be done in build.gradle? Current build file looks like below:

> android {
>
> ```
> ...
>
> buildTypes {
>     release {
>         signingConfig signingConfigs.release
>     }
> }
>
> ...
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Just have separate release/debug versions of the properties file?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33852529/change-properties-file-and-settings-gradle-file-in-android-project-based-on-bui