# Change .properties file and settings.gradle file in android project based on buildType

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a android gradle project where i have two buildTypes: QA and prod. I want to change a property in .properties file depending on the build type. I also want to change one of the value in settings.gradle file based on the buildType. I'm new to android and gradle so excuse me if this is a very basic question.

This is my .properties file:

```
build_number=3.1-SNAPSHOT
version_number=3.1.0
environment_name=prod //this needs to changed to environment_name=qa in qa environment
```

This is my settings.gradle file:

```
rootProject.name = 'tom-android-prod' //this needs to changed to rootProject.name = 'tom-android-qa' in qa environment
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1'

    }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

}

dependencies {
....
}
```

Comment: I don't think that you can do it. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti I want different properties to load based on the buildType. For eg. if the buildType is QA,  environment_name=qa and if buildType is prod, environment_name=prod in .properties file.

Comment: Define a variable in your buildType or simple use different properties (not values) in your. properties file.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti i found an answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9035356/how-can-i-transform-a-properties-file-during-a-gradle-build). But my build.gradle file cannot resolve ant.propertyfile. Any idea what can i am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not real sure what your goal is with the `environment_name` as its not used, but imagine you need to set a variable only for a specific build then you could do something like this:

```
ext {
    environment_name = null
}
android {
    // other stuff...
    buildTypes {
        qa {
            project.ext.environment_name = "qa"
        }
        prod {
            project.ext.environment_name = "prod"
        }
    }
}

// later you can use the variable like this
println "Hello variable: $project.ext.environment_name"
```

Using buildTypes should remove the need to modify the `rootProject.name = 'tom-android'`.  Or you could use the `productFlavors` closure in the same way... depends on what all you want to specify explicitly for each build configuration.